# To create a different page and link from the category view page

Tags: magento-1.7, category

Sorry for confusing in Title. I added some code in "category/catalog/view.phtml page" to display the Sub category and the description.

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories() as $_subcat): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/output')->categoryAttribute($_subcat, $_subcat->getName(), 'name') ?></a>
            <? $current_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subcat->getId()); ?>
            <?php if($current_cat->getId()) { ?>
                <p><?php echo $current_cat->getDescription(); ?></p> 
            <?php }?>
            <a href="">Read More</a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

But now i want to give an link to the "Read More", so that i can create the page for display more description about the category. After that i want to give the `<?php echo $_subcat->getUrl() ?>` link for displaying the category product listing page as the default magento.
Is it possible by creating a .phtml page? If yes, how can i give the link to the .phtml page.

Comment: Hey Ranjit, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about this is to add a new attribute to your categories, let's call it 'read more page' and fill that as a dropdown with all the CMS pages. The admin user would be able to choose a CMS page that he has created with more information about the category.

This approach would require minimal coding. Some documentation that might help you create something like this

**Adding category attribute**

- http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/274144/#t376220
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405834/387136

**Attribute options dropdown**

- Model I've written that fills an array with CMS pages ([Github](https://github.com/sandermangel/rkhomepagewrapper/blob/master/app/code/community/Redkiwi/Rkhomewrapper/Model/Options/Cmspages.php) link)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/14580151/387136 ('how to' link)

Now you can retrieve the ID of the CMS page in the `view.phtml`, load the CMS page and retrieve a link to this page to display

```
<?php if ((int)$_category->getData('read_more_page')): ?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl((int)$_category->getData('read_more_page')); ?>"><?php $this->__('Read more');?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```